# Header Authorization is undefined after using it in a function

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, request, authorization

After receiving an request on my proxy node.js server the header authorization field is properly set when outputting it with "console.log()".
I tried to save it in a different variable and outputting this as well but the "authorization field" will be undefined.

Outputting the whole request will result in a missing "authorization" field in the header when saving it to another variable. When I am only outputting it via "console.log" the authorization field will be present in the header.

If I use the code like this, the `console.log('   Authorization:  ', req.headers.authorization);` has an output:

```
app.use('/Test',function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('   Authorization:  ', req.headers.authorization);
  next();
}, proxy(config.navSoapHost, {
  https: true,
  filter: function(req, res) {     
     return true;
  }, 
  proxyReqOptDecorator: function(proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8';
    return proxyReqOpts;
  }
}))
```

If I use the code like this, both console.logs() return an "undefined":

```
  app.use('/Test',function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('   Authorization:  ', req.headers.authorization);
  var authCode = req.headers.authorization;
  console.log(authCode);
  next();
}, proxy(config.navSoapHost, {
  https: true,
  filter: function(req, res) {     
     return true;
  }, 
  proxyReqOptDecorator: function(proxyReqOpts, srcReq) {
    proxyReqOpts.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8';
    return proxyReqOpts;
  }
}))
```

Why is `req.headers.authorization` undefined whenever I try to use it except for a console.log()?

Comment: Can't really tell what question you're asking.  Can you please try to describe more clearly what you want help with?

Comment: And does the `var authCode = req.headers.authorization;` that you show as commented out work for you?  Still don't understand the question.

Comment: I am trying to read und use the value of "req.headers.authorization" for further actions. But whenever I try to  save the value in another variable or try to use it in something like "str.split()",  it doesn't have a value and is "undefined".

Comment: What do you get when you do `console.log(req.headers.authorization)`?  When you say "save in another variable" and "still doesn't have it's value", it sounds like you're trying some set of code you have not shown us.  Please show us THAT specific code that you're trying.

Comment: No it does not. When I try ```var authCode = req.headers.authorization;``` the value ```req.headers.authorization``` is of type undefined. But if I ```console.log(req.headers.authorization)``` it has a value.

Comment: That does not make sense.  Please edit your question to show two blocks of code, one where you can see the value of `req.headers.authorization` and one where you save it to a variable and cannot see it.  We need to see the EXACT code you say works and the EXACT code you say doesn't work.  Your question is not yet clear on that.

Comment: Edited the question. I know that it doesn't make sense that's why I am asking. I don't change anything else than adding those two lines of code.

Comment: I don't know.  That's weird.  I would set a breakpoint in the middleware function and manually inspect `req.headers` to see what's there.

Comment: I debugged it with both ways and while debugging the ```req.headers.authorization``` is not set at all. 
But if I console.log(req.headers) with the first code, it shows the attribute ```autherization``` with my value.

I also tried to use another attribute from the header. While using another attribute instead of ```autherization``` it seems to work in both ways. I thought that it is maybe a security option that I can't use ```req.header.authorization``` for further actions.

Comment: Do you have other middleware that sets the `req.headers.authorization` value?  Are you 100% sure that's running before you do `var authCode = req.headers.authorization;`?  If `authCode` is an object and not a primitive value, then this could be explained by the fact that `console.log()` is "lazy" and evaluates objects you send it in another thread some time after you call `console.log()`.  You won't see this with a primitive value, but can see it with an object that has its value changed shortly after you call `console.log()`.  This sounds like a plausible explanation.

Comment: So, perhaps you have a timing issue and `req.headers.authorization` isn't yet filled out when your first middleware runs.  But, the delays built into `console.log(req.headers.authorization)` cause it to be able to show you the value after it was filled in.

Comment: The shown middleware is the first and only one that is called after I send a request via soap to the proxy.

Comment: What is the proxy middleware doing?

Comment: At the moment it is only forwarding the request. Later on it should be used to read the authorization value and check if the user is allowed to be forwarded. He will be checked with different criteria. The proxy is used to prevent to many requests at the main server.